# Can't read midi file? [extended specification?]

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, midi

I'm trying to read a midi file in C++ and I'm stuck with an error which seems to be an event not defined in the standard midi spec (retrieved from many sites including this: http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html)

I opened the midi in a HEX editor and pinpointed the error. It happens before the very first "note on" event. The file was generated using Sibelius 6 software and I was wondering that if I post the file section here someone would help me come around this.

This is the beginning of the 3rd track:

```
4D 54 72 6B (MTrk magic number)
00 00 1F F5 (track size in bytes - 8181)
00 FF 03 04 (4 bytes follows) (track sequence name)
00 FF 04 0B (11 bytes follows) (instrument name)
00 C0 34 (program change event)
00 B0 79 00 (controller event)
00 5B <- (what the heck is that?!)
```

It can't be delta ticks since the first value is 00 (no MSB set to 1), it's not a recognizable event either. 10 bytes later I recognize a "note on" event
It goes:

00 5B 30 00 40 00 00 07 64 00 0A 10 **00 90 3E 47** <- note on

I have no idea what those 12 bytes before "note on" represent and therefore cannot read the file. I know that the very first note is quite long maybe that's the reason. I also noticed I couldn't find a event to represent "bar" pauses. Maybe that's the code for a bar + length? Should I read those as ticks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One complexity of MIDI files is [Running Status](http://dogsbodynet.com/fileformats/midi.html#RUNSTATUS). If there's sequence of messages of the same type and channel (eg all controllers or all notes) then MIDI can save a number of bytes by omitting the status byte.  If this didn't use running status then the bytes you would see are:

```
00 B0 79 00 - controller 121: controller reset
00 B0 5B 00 - controller 91: reverb
00 B0 40 00 - controller 64: sustain
00 B0 07 64 - controller 7: volume
00 B0 0A 10 - controller 10: pan
00 90 3E 47 - note message
```

Because all the controller messages are contiguous and are for the same channel, the status byte can be omitted. As soon as there's a change of message type, the status byte has to be added again.

If you're trying to make sense of MIDI files then I would recommend using a separate tool such as [Python-MIDI](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi) or [GNMidi](http://www.gnmidi.com/) as a sanity checker whenever there's a MIDI event you can't make sense of. These can show it as text so you can mimic what it's doing.

EDIT: Another gotcha to be aware of is that any MIDI messages that take a length or duration parameter (eg the time in PPQN between events in a MIDI file, or the length of sysex messages or meta events) uses a variable length, so don't assume all the length fields are always a fixed length.

Disclaimer: I wrote the MIDI export code in Sibelius 6...

Comment: Whoa! Seriously! I went through a boat load of websites describing midi file format and not a single mentioned running status. You just saved my day! One other thing I couldn't figure out is how the paused "bars" on Sibelius are exported to midi? Also, this midi loader is a part of a commercial game and I'd like to give you a special thanks in credits. What name can I put there?

Comment: You need a copy of the [actual MIDI spec](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midispec.php) to get the exact details, though it's not cheap.  If you hunt around you might find a MIDI import library that will deal with the details and save you time.  Regarding pauses (fermata) in Sibelius, as I recall we insert extra time signatures to lengthen the bar. Older versions inserted tempo changes to make the notes longer, but this didn't allow for a gap between the end of the fermata and the start of the next bar.  Oh, and you just can just credit 'The Mandrill' :-)